# Why is script src so slow on with JSDOM on AWS CentOS?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-plus, mocha.js, jsdom

Trying to figure out why Node/NPM/Mocha/JSDOM can't complete some tests on AWS CentOS machines.  These tests run in less than 100ms on my localhost, but timeout after 60s on CentOS.  For example, one test is to src the googlePlus js into the DOM.

the method in test is:

```
_loadGooglePlusApi: function() {
    var r = false;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    /* explicitly render g+ button widgets in components */
    window.__gcfg = {
        "parsetags": "explicit"
    };

    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (!r && (!script.readyState || script.ready === 'complete')) {
            r = true;
            this.dispatch(constants.GOOGLEPLUS_INIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }.bind(this);
}
```

And the test context contains a global window and DOM

```
global.jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = jsdom;
global.window = document.parentWindow;
```

And my error is just a timeout:

```
  2) app/utils/api.js api.user.login.googlePlus TBD:
     Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
      at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/www/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:170:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

Response times are pretty erratic for any of the tests that require some sort of http outbound connection.  Works everytime on localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your security group setup to allow requests to the external locations as well as the responses?

Comment: The groups are not set up to block outbound 80. They accept inbound any.  Do they need to be explicitly set to allow outbound 80?

Comment: The way you describe it sounds correct to me